# Extend Class Based Component With Typescript Vuejs3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, class

I have two component and I want to use one of them as an abstract component on vuejs 3. But I have got an error such as I can not use @Options on child component. But I was extend Vue on abstract component and I am waiting for use.

Abstract Component

```
import {Vue} from "vue-class-component";
import {Prop} from "vue-property-decorator";
import {InputTypeEnums} from "@/libs/namespaces/";

export default class AbstractInputComponent extends Vue {

@Prop() type!: InputTypeEnums;
@Prop() name!: string;
@Prop() placeholder?: string;
@Prop() label?: string;
@Prop() isDisabled = false;

constructor() {
  super();
}

}
```

Child Component

```
import {AbstractInputComponent} from "@/libs/components/abstracts";
import {Options} from "vue-class-component";

@Options({
  name: 'Input'
})

export default class InputComponent extends AbstractInputComponent {}
```